# How to construct a proof of $A = (A\cap B)\cup (A-B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Constructing a Venn diagram is not enough as a proof, how would I go about actually proving $A = (A\cap B)\cup(A−B)$?

Comment: The general approach to prove two sets are the same will work easily here. Assume $x\in A$ and then show that it must either be in $(A\cap B)\cup(A-B)$. Next show that if  $x\in(A\cap B)\cup(A- B)$ then it must be in $A$. If you understand what these sets are, then the proof is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

$A-B$ is the set difference. Thus, by definition, $A-B=A\cap B^c$ where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$.

Clearly, though, $A\cap B$ and $A-B$ are disjoint groups (if an element is in $B$ then it cannot be in $A-B$)

Now, we have $(A\cap B) \cup (A\cap B^c)=A$ which you can show by checking the different scenarios whenever $x\in A$, $x\in B$, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest always using basic set algebra whenever possible (it is much easier and efficient than constructing an element-chasing proof). Let $U$ be the universal set and consider the following:
\begin{align}
(A\cap B)\cup(A-B)&= (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c)\tag{by definition}\\[1em]
&= A\cap(B\cup B^c)\tag{distributivity}\\[1em]
&= A\cap U \tag{complement}\\[1em]
&= A.\tag{identity}
\end{align}

Comment: [Here's a link to the Set Algebra laws that were used here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra).

Answer (score 1):

Like most set equality proofs to prove $A = B$ you do two steps:  1) Chose an $x \in A$ and show that therefore $x \in B$ and therefore $A \subseteq B$.  And then 2) Choose an $x \in B$ and show that therefore $B \subseteq A$.  We can conclude if $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ that it must be $A = B$.

So we need to prove the two following:

I) $x \in A \implies x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A - B)$

II) $x  \in (A \cap B) \cup (A - B) \implies x \in A$.

To prove I)

$x \in A$.  Either $x \in B$ or $x \not \in B$.  If $x \in B$ then $x \in A \cap B \subset (A \cap B) \cup (A-B)$.  If $x \not \in B$ then $x \in A - B \subset (A \cap B) \cup (A - B)$.

Either way $x \in  (A \cap B) \cup (A - B)$

To prove II)

$x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A - B)$.  That means either $x \in (A \cap B)$ or $x \in A - B$. If $x \in A \cap B \subset A$ then $x \in A$.  If $x \in A - B \subset A$ then $x \in A$.

Either way $x \in A$.

====

Or we could do this directly by definitions.

$(A \cap B) \cup (A - B)$

By definition $X \cup Y = \{x|x \in X \text{ or } x \in Y\}$

So$(A \cap B) \cup (A-B) = \{x|x \in A \cap B \text{ or } x \in A-B\}$

But $A \cap B = \{x| x \in A \text{ and } x \in B\}$ and $A - B = \{x| x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in B\}$

So$(A \cap B) \cup (A-B) = \{x|x \in A \text { and } x \in B \text { OR } x \in A \text { and } x \not \in B\}$

$= \{x|x \in A \text { and } [x \in B \text { OR }  x \not \in B]\}$

$= \{x|x \in A\} = A$.

=====

Or once you get comfortable with manipulating sets:

i)$A - B = A \cap B^c$ and

ii)$(X \cap Y) \cup (X \cup Z) = X \cap (Y \cup Z)$

(you have to have been comfortable and seen those statements proven)

So $(A \cap B) \cup (A - B) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) = A \cap (B \cup B^c) = A \cap (\text{Universe Set}) = A$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\cap B=\varnothing$ then it's trivial.
Suppose then $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$. If $x\in A$ then we have 2 cases: $x\in B$ or $x\notin B$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in A-B$. Hence $x\in (A\cap B)\cup (A-B)$.

Converse inclusion is analogous if $x\in (A\cap B)\cup (A-B)$ then $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in A-B$ in both cases $x\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be universal set.
By definition $A-B=A\cap B^c $, substitute this in equation

$(A\cap B) \cup (A-B)=(A\cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$
$=((A\cap B) \cup A) \cap ((A \cap B) \cup B^c)$
$=A \cap ((A \cup B^c)\cap(B \cup B^c))$
$=A\cap((A\cup B^c)\cap S)$
$=A \cap (A\cup B^c)$
$=A$

Answer (score 0):

You could use indicator functions.

- $1_{A\cap B}=1_A1_B$
- $1_A^c=1-1_A$
- $1_{A-B}=1_A-1_A1_B$
- $1_{C\cup D}=1_C+1_D-1_C1_D$

---

So:
$$1_{(A\cap B)\cup(A-B)}=1_A1_B+(1_A-1_A1_B)-1_A1_B(1_A-1_A1_B)=1_A$$