# Usefulness of the characteristic function (set-theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First a **definition** for those who need it: If $S$ is a set and $S_0$ is a subset of $S$ then the characteristic function of $S_0$ as a subset of $S$ is the function $f$, with domain $S$ defined by $f(s) = 1$ if $s \in S_0$ and $f(s) = 0$ if $s \notin S_0$.

The definition is clear and I understand the proof of the theorem that for any set $S$ the set of any characteristic function with domain $S$ has the same cardinality as the power set of $S$. But I'm failing to see what purpose it will play in what sorts of problems. Can anyone give an example of a problem for which the solution includes introducing the characteristic function of a set?

**Edit** I believe it is also known as the Indicator function (as per Wikipedia).

**Edit 2** I mostly mean applications to problems in elementary set theory.

Comment: As noted on wikipedia under [basic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Basic_properties) the characteristic (indicator) function can be used to describe set relations using boolean algebra. The inclusion-exclusion principle can be derived this way, for example.

Comment: Re `Edit 2` see actual usage examples in some answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897713/proof-of-the-set-identity-a-cap-b-cup-c-a-capb-cup-c-iff-c-subseteq-a/1897733), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413951/indicator-function-distributive-property-proof) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804728/how-to-construct-a-proof-of-a-a-cap-b-cup-a-b/1804810).

Answer (score 1):

Any analysis problem! For instance, you define the Riemann integral using characteristic functions of appropriate subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

One of the uses of indicator functions is that they make it possible to translate statements about sets to statements about functions. This is sometimes very useful.

Other applications can be found in integration theory. Here we approximate the function we want to integrate by step-functions, which can be defined in terms of indicator functions.

Another application can be found in the theory of commutative C*-algebras, which are always isomorphic to some space of continuous functions on some topological space. Once you're familiar with the idiom of C*-algebras, it is easy to see that a projection in a commutative C*-algebra precisely corresponds to an indicator function on a clopen subset.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the first paragraph? It's the application I'm most interested in for my current purposes. For example, what's a particular problem in set theory for which this "translation" would be useful?

Comment: I am not a set theorist, but what comes to mind is the concept of a recursive function (= a computable function) vs. a recursive set (a set whose indicator function is recursive). Roughly, a recursive set can be seen as a set for which there is an algorithm that decides whether or not it contains any given element. These sets and functions play an important role in for instance the proof of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem.